# Blender 2.82a in Texture Paint mode Paint Mask doesn't show wireframe

Tags: texture-painting, weight-painting, masking, wireframe

Hi I am new to blender and really struggling to find answer on this.

I am not able to show wireframe while in Texture Paint mode, supposed to be shown in any tutorial. Turning on Paint Mask is not helping, However WHen I switch to Weight Paint mode toggling on Paint Mask  shows wireframe correctly.

[image: Paint Mask doesn't show wireframe]

Answer (score 1):

In the Properties Editor under the Object Properties panel, You can turn on the Wireframe and All Edges options there to get wireframe over your texture paint.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but that solution is for general case, here People are having wireframe even when it is turned off, and you can see I also have wireframe showing without checking the options you mentioned. however that wireframe seems not working in Paint mode. this is not a blocking issue Just want to find a solution,

Comment: What tutorial are you following that shows the wireframe while in Texture Paint mode other than when using Face Masking? I haven't seen one yet, and the reason it is no concern for me is that when sampling with the S key, I do not want to sample wire color by accident. I assume there is some workflow issue you find that you need a solution for, but maybe you could explain better what it is you want to achieve then so someone might find an answer for you.

Comment: I ment not paint mask off, but the wireframe off from Object properties. in my example I have that wireframe visible in weight paint mode but not in texture paint mode. enabling wireframe from object properties fixes it sure, but that is general solution. want to know what am I missing why in weight paint mode I see wireframe when I turn Paint Mask on and in texture paint no...

but actually I foudn out that it was not very necessary to see wireframes. so even without solution I am fine.

Comment: Wireframe was removed from texture paint to avoid confusion with errors on swatch sampling, if I remember correctly. Even in face select masking, they tried to eliminate the internal wireframe of the selection if more than one face.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you very much